# getting Invalid column index when calling Procedural

Tags: java, jdbc

I have Procedural that is takes two String arguments and returns Integer value from database Oracle 10g .

When try to print out the result I'm getting Invalid column index .

the code is

```
  try {


             Dbconnection NewConnect = new Dbconnection();
             Connection con = NewConnect.MakeConnect();

            CallableStatement stmt1 = ((Connection) con).prepareCall("{ call login (?, ?, ?)}");
            stmt1.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
            stmt1.setString(2, "ahmed");
            stmt1.setString(3, "ahmed");

             ResultSet rslt = stmt1.executeQuery();

             if (rslt.next())
             {

                 System.out.println( rslt.getInt(1)); 
             }
```

Procedural  login

```
   create or replace 
    PROCEDURE login

        (p_username  teacher.username%TYPE,
                    p_password  teacher.password%TYPE)


    IS
           v_teacher_id   teacher.teacher_id%TYPE;
                      v_username    teacher.username%TYPE ;
           v_password     teacher.password%TYPE ;


    BEGIN
SELECT   teacher_id, username , password
INTO    v_teacher_id , v_username , v_password
FROM    teacher

 where username = p_username and password =p_password  ;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_teacher_id);



     end login ;
```

Comment: You must get the result of the `CallableStatement` in a `ResultSet` and then consume the `ResultSet` by calling `ResultSet#next` first and then accessing to the results.

Comment: Adding to the above comment, i want to say is that stored procedure do not return value, function does that.

Comment: @Noob UnChained  ooh it's important comment , i going to create func instend of Procedural  .. right ?

Comment: Stored Procedures can return values through `OUT` parameters or as in your case `ResultSet`s. Just call `next()` before invoking the getter like Luiggi said.

Comment: plaese look , i have editied my Post , but it tell me : line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'LOGIN'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

Answer (score 0):

Nice Try But Some error exists here....
Do it like this... your output you will retrive for 100% sure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE login

(           v_teacher_id OUT teacher.teacher_id%TYPE,
                    p_username  IN teacher.username%TYPE,
                    p_password  IN teacher.password%TYPE)
    IS ..... (blah blah blah)
```

Tell Me onething, if you are not providing any Output parameter at start of the  procedure , how you can expect the output in Java code ?

Now try, you will get your output from the java Code

```
 rslt.getInt(1)
```

All the very best :)... Surajit